# Communicate with a driver - OS X

Tags: macos, kernel, driver

Given a very simple IO driver :

```
class com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest : public IOService
{
    OSDeclareDefaultStructors(com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest)

    public:
        virtual bool init (OSDictionary* dictionary = nullptr);
        virtual void free(void);
        virtual IOService* probe (IOService* provider, SInt32* score);
        virtual bool start (IOService* provider);
        virtual void stop (IOService* provider);
};
```

Here's the PLIST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>IOKitTest</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.osxkernel.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>IOClass</key>
    <string>com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest</string>
    <key>IOMatchCategory</key>
    <string>com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest</string>
    <key>IOProviderClass</key>
    <string>IOResources</string>
    <key>IOResourceMatch</key>
    <string>IOKit</string>
</dict>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
<key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
<string>9.0.0</string>
<key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
<string>9.0.0</string>
</dict>
 </plist>
```

The driver runs perfectly fine and I can see it using the 'kernel log' and also when typing:

```
kextstat | grep -v com.apple
```

Problem is that I have no idea how to communicate it using a User Space application, how do I locate it?
I know that it has something to do with the dictionary and I tried using the following code to find it but no luck (Used apple developer website):

```
int search_driver ()
{
io_iterator_t iter = 0;
io_service_t service = 0;
kern_return_t kr;

CFDictionaryRef matchingDict = IOServiceMatching("IOResources");
kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, matchingDict, &iter);
if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Nothing found. \n");
    return -1;
}
// Iterate over all matching objects.
while ((service = IOIteratorNext(iter)) != 0)
{
    CFStringRef     className;
    io_name_t       name;
    // List all IOUSBDevice objects, ignoring objects that subclass IOUSBDevice.
    className = IOObjectCopyClass(service);
    IORegistryEntryGetName(service, name);

    printf("Found device with name: %s\n", name);
    CFRelease(className);
    IOObjectRelease(service);
    // Release the iterator.
    IOObjectRelease(iter);
}
return 0;
}
```

I tried :

```
CFDictionaryRef matchingDict = IOServiceMatching("IOResources");
CFDictionaryRef matchingDict = IOServiceMatching("IOService");
```

and more.

but still no luck. The first one finds: IOResources
The second one finds: Macbook Air 5,2

What am I doing wrong ? How do I locate the running driver and communicate with it using a simple user space application?

Answer (score 2):

What does your IOKitTest implementation file look like? In that file, you will need to register for the service by calling registerService() in order for it to be found by the client. It could be added in the start function, for example:

```
bool com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest::start (IOService *provider)
{
    bool res = super::start(provider);
    super::registerService(); // <---- add this
    IOLog("IOKitTest::start\n");
    return res;
}
```

Then in your search_driver() function you can then look for your exact class instead of the IOResources nub.

```
matchingDict = IOServiceMatching("com_osxkernel_driver_IOKitTest");
```

There is some older documentation around with examples of these functions without a registerService() call which will not work on newer systems. Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Hi! I know it is a little to old, but I'm facing the same problem. I tried calling `registerService()` with no luck. Any ideas? Thanks!